# MySQL - Storing an Array of Strings within Table

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a table for which each row of data represents a screening event for a movie, displayed to the user as an image gallery.

The data fields are:

`id` `mainImage` `movie` `venue` `location` `date`

Each screening event is:

- for one `movie`
- at one `venue`
- at one `location`
- on one `date`

..and the string in `mainImage` is a URL to an image that represents the first image in a gallery.

I'm at a crossroads with how I should include the rest of the images for each screening. I can think of two possible routes:

1. Add a new column `imageArray` that is an array of strings, each string being a URL to an image from the same screening. These don't have to be in any particular order, so I feel like this could be a very good option. But is this the right way to do something like this?
2. Create separate tables containing just image URLs and somehow join them to this table? This seems needlessly complicated, but is this how something like this would be done?

..Or would this sort of thing be done some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data lends itself well to the following two tables:

```
event
id | movieId | venue | location | date

images
id | movieId | imageId | imageURL
```

Here the `event` table is largely the same as what you originally had.  However, I created a separate table to contain the images associated with each movie.

This is just a suggestion, and your actual table definitions might require more information.  To be clear though, it is probably a bad idea to consider adding more *columns* for each image URL.  The reason is that you may not know how many URLs you will need in the future.  Adding more columns to a table is a big hassle, but with my suggestion adding more rows to a table is relatively easy.

Comment: I see. So in the second table, it would be a bunch of rows of images, and the movieID could be non-unique, so a bunch of them could have the same movieID that's associated to one screening event in the first table?

Comment: @coffeebot Yes, you're spot on.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. That was very helpful.